# mpiexec: unable to start all procs; may have invalid machine names

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I  am new to MPI and MPICH.

I have installed mpich on two machines having : Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.

mpicc -v has version 1.2.1p1.

I have added entries in /etc/hosts for both client and master in both machines.

Added SSH configurations for passwordless remote ssh.

While running command :

> mpiexec -np 3 -host master ./a.out : -np 3 -host client ./a.out

The system responds with

> mpiexec: unable to start all procs; may have invalid machine names
>
> remaining specified hosts:
>
> 107.109.110.219 (master)
>
> 107.108.87.33 (client)

Request you to please suggest if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the host file for the MPI implementation as well. For OpenMPI you can have a look at the following page:

https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-hostfile

Here it is described how to set it up. I have linked the OpenMPI one because it is more clear. Here you can find a tutorial that uses MPICH and explains how to set up the host file:

http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/

Comment: Hi Chiel, Thanks for references. However, I am already using -host options to specify the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I installed mpich initially by apt-get. I think this caused the stated problem.

To Fix I did following and it fixed the problem :

1. Uninstalled the mpich installed via apt-get.
2. Downloaded and compiled mpich v3.2 source as per steps of mpich user guide.
3. After this , one of the machines had a problem of missing libudev.so.0, as a temporary solution , installed libudev.so.1 and soft linked libudev.so.0 to it.

After these 3 steps, mpiexec is running properly for machines.